# How to kill a process in shell script which is running through cron?

Tags: shell-script, cron, openwrt

I have a shell script which runs in cronjob. This shell script has to kill a process which is running and start the new process again.

When I run the script manually it works perfectly fine, but when it runs through cron it does not kill the old process but starts a new process along with the old one.

I am using the below line of code to kill the process:

kill -9 ps | grep "server1" | grep -v grep | awk '{ print $1 }'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to indicate what to kill:

```
kill -9 $(ps | grep "server1" | grep -v grep | awk '{ print $1 }')
```

You can also use the trick:

```
kill -9 $(ps | grep "server[1]" | awk '{ print $1 }')
```

Comment: kill -9 `ps | grep "server1" | grep -v grep | awk '{ print $1 }'`... Using back tics instead of braces

Comment: $() and `` are equivalent.

Answer (score 3):

In the **purest** form, you can use

`pkill server1`

That assumes `server1` is actually the process name, not just somewhere in the command line - otherwise add an `-f`.

`pkill -f server1CommandArgument`

**But wait!**

You can **test what `pkill` will match** and kill with the command `pgrep` - which is technically almost the same. The difference it: instead of killing, it **prints the PID**.

Try these - list the matching PIDs:

`pgrep server1`

`-l` lists the **process name** too, not only the PID:

`pgrep -l server1`

`-f` **matches the command line**, not only the name:

`pgrep -fl server1`

When you want to kill the processes that are matched by `pgrep`,
leave out the `-l`, and add a signal, if you want something else than the default SIGTERM, `-15`:

`pkill -9 server1`

As your example uses a plain `ps` command, which matches only processes on the current terminal by default, take care what is matched by your command, as `pgrep` and `pkill` are not matching only processes on the current terminal.

---

A side note on using `kill -9` - it is the **most violent way to kill**;
are you sure that's **actually needed**?

That may not matter, depending on what kind of program killed. But you should not do it without a good reason to a program/server that may save any data do files, writes lock files, etc. As long as a programm does not badly hang, a `kill` using the default signal `-15` would do.

Answer (score 0):

Inside shell script you have to skip `sh` also. Below command worked for me.

```
ps -aef | grep $1 | grep -v sh| grep -v grep| awk '{print $2}'
```

Script:

```
#!/bin/bash
var=`ps -aef | grep $1 | grep -v sh| grep -v grep| awk '{print $2}'`
if [ !-z "$var"]
then
  echo $1 process is not running 
else
  kill -9 $var
  echo $1 process killed forcefully, process id $var.
fi
```

Reference:  [Force Kill linux process in shell script](http://w3devops.com/force-kill-linux-unix-process-shell-script/) can go through the article for full explanation.

Comment: You might describe the link contents here.

Comment: The reference link above threw spyware warnings from my ad blocker. It appears to have been hijacked, so proceed with caution.